# How the expression evaluates?

Tags: c, expression

can some one draw the precedence tree for the expression and please explain the side effects..values after the expression evaluation in C.

```
int i=-3, j=2, k=0, m;
m= ++i || ++j&&++k;
```

according to me  output should be -2 3 1 1 but my gnu c compiler printing is -2 2 0 1?
i want to know how?

Answer (score 8):

Because `j` won't be evaluated due to [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
m= ++i || ++j && ++k;
    ↑
```

At this stage, `m` is already evaluated to 1 regardless of the right side of the `||`. Why?

Because `1 || anything` is 1.

Comment: but ++ has more precedence than || so i think ++j shud be evaluated first along with other ++ operators?

Comment: Precedence is about parsing, short-circuit-evaluation is about execution. Precedence determines how the expression is interpreted, whereas execution rules determine what the code actually does.

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` and `||` operators in `C` short-circuit. This means that if the value of their left hand side is enough to determine the overall value, the right hand side is never evaluated.

Your expression is parsed as `(++i) || ((++j)&&(++k))`. `||` short circuits, so after `++i` has been evaluated, and its value has been found to be `-2` (a `true` value), no more of the expression is evaluated.